# Simple ROM bit cell

Tags: digital-logic, rom, logisim

I was reading about [ROM example](https://computationstructures.org/lectures/combinational/combinational.html#24) from Computation Structures.

Here is the ROM example mentioned in the lecture.

[image: Read-only Memory(ROM)]

I set up a simple circuit to understand the inner working logic of the circuit.

[image: ROM cell]

When I try to simulate this circuit in [Digital](https://github.com/hneemann/Digital) software when A becomes HIGH it gives an error like this.

[image: Digital Error]

When A is HIGH, Y output should also be a HIGH, right?

**Update:**
I think it works as it's supposed to be after adding a pull up resistor.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the pull-up resistor so the FET would simply short out your power supply.